# How to loop through lists dynamically

Tags: python, loops

With the following function...

```
def func(listA,listB):
    for i in listA:
        for j in listB:
            print(i+j)
```

...is there a way of making it dynamic so it can accept any number of lists ( `func(*args)` ) and still carry out the same procedure? So for example, if you provided 3 lists, it would go:

```
func(listA,listB,listC)
RUN:
for i in listA:
    for j in listB:
          for k in listC:
               print(i+j+k)
```

4 lists:

```
func(listA,listB,listC,listD)

RUN:
for i in listA:
    for j in listB:
        for k in listC:
            for l in listD:
                print(l+j+k+l)
```

...etc

I have explored using a dictionary and while loop but i still keep facing the same issue of how to make Python aware of the lists that should be considered in the loops.

Comment: `itertools.product`.